# Not able to access the key value of a list in a twig file

Tags: theming, hooks

I'm trying to access the key of a list (Text) in a paragraph twig file

This is what I have in my list
small|Small Item 
big|Big Item

```
{{content.field_option.0['#context'].value}}
{% set value = content.field_option.0['#markup'] %}
{{ value }}
```

I always got the text. Small Item or Big Item. I would like to obtain small or big of course depending of the user selection.

I'm going to use this value as an HTML Class.

Thanks for your help

Comment: That's a valid quest(ion), there is no need to down-vote it without leaving a comment on how to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the `entity_view_display` of my paragraph so that my field output the key, instead of the value. I was then able to access the key. I hope that helps?

I'm able to use this: `content.field_button_chrome[0]['#markup']`

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two options:

- Option 1: Change the Display of that field from default to key and use `{{ content.field_name.0 }}`
- Option 2: Do not use content settings and get the what the entity (paragraph, node etc.) sees: `{{ paragraph.field_name.0.value }}` for radio/select fields or for multi value fields:

  ```
  {% for k,v in paragraph.field_variant %}
    {{ v.value }}
  {% endfor %}
  ```

See also [Getting Drupal 8 field values in Twig > List > Keys](https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-drupal-8-field-values-in-twig-22b80cb609bd#5119).